# python code error for movie project "TypeError: this constructor takes no arguments"

Tags: python-2.7

I am working on a code project for Udacity and I get these 2 errors I dont get I have attached the pictures. One error is with parenthesis and when I remove the parenthesis I get an error on the code saying invalid syntax.

```
    import webbrowser

    class Movie():
        valid_ratings = ["G", "R", "PG-13", "R"]

        def _init_(self, movie_title, movie_storyline, poster_image,
                   trailer_youtube):
            self.title = movie_title
            self.storyline = movie_storyline
            self.poster_image_url = poster_image
            self.trailer_youtube_url = trailer_youtube

        def show_trailer(self):
             webbrowser.open(self.trailer_youtube_url)
   import fresh_tomatoes
import media


toy_story = media.Movie("Toy Story",
                        "A story of a boy and his toys come to life",
                        "http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/1/13/Toy_Story.jpg",
                        "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vwyZH85NQC4")

The_devils_double = media.Movie("The_devils_double",
                                "The story of the son of sadam hussain's body double",
                                "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/4/4c/The_Devil%27s_Double.jpg",
                                "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2-MsGEWFiYg",)

Movie_300 = media.Movie("300",
                  "300 spartans vs an amry of persians",
                  "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/5/5c/300poster.jpg",
                  "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wDiUG52ZyHQ")

Ratatouille = media.Movie("Ratatouille",
                          "A rat is a chef in paris",
                          "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/5/50/RatatouillePoster.jpg",
                          "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c3sBBRxDAqk")
Star_Wars_Episode_III = media.Movie("Star_Wars_Episode_III",
                                    "Akin Skywalker goes dark",
                                    "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/9/93/Star_Wars_Episode_III_Revenge_of_the_Sith_poster.jpg",
                                    "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5UnjrG_N8hU")

Office_Space = media.Movie("Office_Space ",
                           "A movie about how work sucks",
                           "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/8/8e/Office_space_poster.jpg",
                           "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kwQziVIzDeg")
#movies = [toy_story, The_devils_double, 300, Ratatouille, Star_Wars_Episode_III , Office_Space  ]
fresh_tomatoes.open_movies_page(movies)
print(media.Movie.valid_ratings)

import webbrowser
import os
import re


# Styles and scripting for the page
main_page_head = '''
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Fresh Tomatoes!</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap 3 -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css" media="screen">
        body {
            padding-top: 80px;
        }
        #trailer .modal-dialog {
            margin-top: 200px;
            width: 640px;
            height: 480px;
        }
        .hanging-close {
            position: absolute;
            top: -12px;
            right: -12px;
            z-index: 9001;
        }
        #trailer-video {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
        }
        .movie-tile {
            margin-bottom: 20px;
            padding-top: 20px;
        }
        .movie-tile:hover {
            background-color: #EEE;
            cursor: pointer;
        }
        .scale-media {
            padding-bottom: 56.25%;
            position: relative;
        }
        .scale-media iframe {
            border: none;
            height: 100%;
            position: absolute;
            width: 100%;
            left: 0;
            top: 0;
            background-color: white;
        }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
        // Pause the video when the modal is closed
        $(document).on('click', '.hanging-close, .modal-backdrop, .modal', function (event) {
            // Remove the src so the player itself gets removed, as this is the only
            // reliable way to ensure the video stops playing in IE
            $("#trailer-video-container").empty();
        });
        // Start playing the video whenever the trailer modal is opened
        $(document).on('click', '.movie-tile', function (event) {
            var trailerYouTubeId = $(this).attr('data-trailer-youtube-id')
            var sourceUrl = 'http://www.youtube.com/embed/' + trailerYouTubeId + '?autoplay=1&html5=1';
            $("#trailer-video-container").empty().append($("<iframe></iframe>", {
              'id': 'trailer-video',
              'type': 'text-html',
              'src': sourceUrl,
              'frameborder': 0
            }));
        });
        // Animate in the movies when the page loads
        $(document).ready(function () {
          $('.movie-tile').hide().first().show("fast", function showNext() {
            $(this).next("div").show("fast", showNext);
          });
        });
    </script>
</head>
'''


# The main page layout and title bar
main_page_content = '''
  <body>
    <!-- Trailer Video Modal -->
    <div class="modal" id="trailer">
      <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <a href="#" class="hanging-close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">
            <img src="https://lh5.ggpht.com/v4-628SilF0HtHuHdu5EzxD7WRqOrrTIDi_MhEG6_qkNtUK5Wg7KPkofp_VJoF7RS2LhxwEFCO1ICHZlc-o_=s0#w=24&h=24"/>
          </a>
          <div class="scale-media" id="trailer-video-container">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Main Page Content -->
    <div class="container">
      <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="navbar-header">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Fresh Tomatoes Movie Trailers</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
      {movie_tiles}
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
'''


# A single movie entry html template
movie_tile_content = '''
<div class="col-md-6 col-lg-4 movie-tile text-center" data-trailer-youtube-id="{trailer_youtube_id}" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#trailer">
    <img src="{poster_image_url}" width="220" height="342">
    <h2>{movie_title}</h2>
</div>
'''


def create_movie_tiles_content(movies):
    # The HTML content for this section of the page
    content = ''
    for movie in movies:
        # Extract the youtube ID from the url
        youtube_id_match = re.search(
            r'(?<=v=)[^&#]+', movie.trailer_youtube_url)
        youtube_id_match = youtube_id_match or re.search(
            r'(?<=be/)[^&#]+', movie.trailer_youtube_url)
        trailer_youtube_id = (youtube_id_match.group(0) if youtube_id_match
                              else None)

        # Append the tile for the movie with its content filled in
        content += movie_tile_content.format(
            movie_title=movie.title,
            poster_image_url=movie.poster_image_url,
            trailer_youtube_id=trailer_youtube_id
        )
    return content


def open_movies_page(movies):
    # Create or overwrite the output file
    output_file = open('fresh_tomatoes.html', 'w')

    # Replace the movie tiles placeholder generated content
    rendered_content = main_page_content.format(
        movie_tiles=create_movie_tiles_content(movies))

    # Output the file
    output_file.write(main_page_head + rendered_content)
    output_file.close()

    # open the output file in the browser (in a new tab, if possible)
    url = os.path.abspath(output_file.name)
    webbrowser.open('file://' + url, new=2)
```

Comment: I am trying to add the code but it says I need to a reputation of 10 to add more than 10 links as my code includes links, I will add code in a moment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your init method has single underscores. It needs to have double underscores before and after "init".

```
def __init__(self, movie_title, movie_storyline, poster_image, trailer_youtube):
```

Also, you're missing a comma when you create the `Movie_300` object. It should look like this (with a comma after the wikimedia link):

```
Movie_300 = Movie("300",
                  "300 spartans vs an amry of persians",
                  "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/5/5c/300poster.jpg",
                  "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wDiUG52ZyHQ")
```

As an aside, the [convention](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#naming-conventions) to name variables in Python is to use all lowercase.

Comment: Hi thanks I will try that, I uploaded my code so you take a better look.

Comment: I tired your fix but I got this errror   , line 17, in <module>
    "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/5/5c/300poster.jpg"
TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 5 arguments (4 given)

Comment: You're missing a comma in `Movie_300` after the 3rd argument.

Comment: I added the comma after the 3rd argument and I got this error                         line 15, in <module>
    Movie_300 = Movie("300",
NameError: name 'Movie' is not defined

Comment: I was able to fix some of the errors the last error I believe I am getting is fresh_tomatoes.open_movies_page(movies) NameError: name 'movies' is not define

Comment: @J1N1 I'm glad I helped you fix your original problem, but stack overflow isn't a code writing service. Since you said that my answer fixed your original problem, I'd appreciate it if you marked it as the solution. Hint for your last problem: You haven't defined the movies variable yet since it's commented out.

Comment: Thanks Evan, I will take a look at that, and I will mark it as solution